# Return dataframe variable on multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe, multiprocessing

I want to import (pd.read_pickle) 4 files at the same time but later in the code I can't use the variables. How can I get the returned dataframes of the functions on multiprocessing.

```
def a():
    df1 = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\bi\cache\ventas.pkl")
    return df1
def b():
    df2 = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\bi\cache\altas.pkl")
    return df2
def c():
    df3 = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\bi\cache\vali.pkl")
    return df3
def d():
    df4 = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\bi\cache\cuotas.pkl")
    return df4

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = a)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = b)
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target = c)
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target = d)

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

print(df1)
```

Comment: A Process object can't return the result of a calculation. You can use a Queue or (my recommendation) a "multiprocessing.Pool" which cares about most of the details. A process can never set variables in another process directly.

Comment: there are ways to do it, but, passing dataframes around processes will involve pickling and unpickling then anyway.  So you will loose any performance gain you might have from using several processes to unpickle the data in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your file names, it appears you are running under Windows. If so, any code that creates child processes must be invoked from a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Whether you can save any time by using multiprocessing is questionable. The worker functions `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are possibly too trivial and doing concurrent disk I/O will be counter-productive unless you have a solid-state drive with a high bandwidth. Using a `multiprocessing.Pool` per Michael Butscher's comment would like the following.

```py
import pandas as pd

def a():
    df1 = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\bi\cache\ventas.pkl")
    return df1

def b():
    df2 = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\bi\cache\altas.pkl")
    return df2

def c():
    df3 = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\bi\cache\vali.pkl")
    return df3

def d():
    df4 = pd.read_pickle(r"C:\xampp\htdocs\bi\cache\cuotas.pkl")
    return df4

if __name__=='__main__':
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    
    with Pool(4) as pool:
        async_results = [pool.apply_async(worker) for worker in (a, b, c, d)]
        results = [async_result.get() for async_result in async_results]
        # Unpack:
        df1, df2, df3, df4 = results
        print(df1)
```